# Returning application/json content-type for .json files on RHEL/Apache

Tags: json, apache, mime, rhel

OS is specifically RHEL6 running Apache2.

So in my Apache configuration, I have:

```
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
```

And in `/etc/mime.types`, I have the following:

```
application/json                                json
```

Yet when requesting a file with the `.json` extension (and containing valid JSON), the content-type is set to `text/html`.  Any idea how I can force the correct header for this file type?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `AddType` directive in the apache configuration:

> AddType application/json .json

Comment: Works in .htaccess too.

Comment: It does not work on one of my server. 
Any other tip ?